# How to make vscode debugging in the terminal less verbose?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I CTRL + F5, the terminal output shows verbosity that I would like to hide:

> `cd /home/ ; env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 /usr/bin/python3 /home/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.2.64397/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --nodebug --client --host localhost --port 33907 /home/hello.py` 
>   `Hello`

Just print Hello...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to hide this output as it's required to execute the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

to make terminal logs less verbose, you can pipe in `grep` afterward, as below:

`your-original-command | grep -v ”substitute beginning of what you don't want to see between these quotes”`

the `v` flag will hide all instances of lines beginning with the matched string

so, for instance, if you wanted to hide all lines beginning with `blah blah yada yada`, you could 
`your-original-command | grep -v ”blah”`

https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Comment: I am talking about when debugging python with vscode. The code outputs to the terminal window, this has nothing to do with grep am afraid.